# When to use single table vs multiple tables in mysql, Oracle?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a somewhat long form on a website.

```
fName
lName
email
phoneNumber
streetAddress
zip
age
dob
jobTitle
company
income
```

Client is using Oracle and I need to send the data there. I have no experience with Oracle as my company doesn't use/need it.

My question is: Should I be using multiple tables or just one large table? Does it really matter? I'd prefer using a single table but I am unsure if that will cause issues to arise on their end using Oracle.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question does not provide enough information to give you an answer.  Multiple tables for what?  How are you transmitting it from your website to the client's Oracle server?

Comment: Regardless of the database, for an OLTP application, you'd almost certainly want to start with a database in third normal form and adjust the data model from there.  Whether that would involve one table or multiple tables for that list of attributes depends entirely on the data.  Is one person allowed to have multiple phone numbers, multiple addresses, multiple jobs, etc?

Comment: @kevin I was planning on building the site and sql db hosted on Hostgator. I thought I import the table from the sql data saved on my webhost to their Oracle app.

Answer (score -2):

Generally speaking, you only need as many tables as you need to keep your data organized and secure. However you should follow the compliance standards for dealing with personally identifiable information on publicly facing services. Some of them are enforced by federal law. Read up on this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_security), and [here](http://www.gsa.gov/portal/content/104256) at the government for a general overview, and go from there.

That being said, I can tell you'll likely need a minimum of 4 tables. Generally speaking, information that is a matter of public record can be located in the same table, however for safety sake, the persons name is generally divorced from other matters of public record such as address and phone number. Email is also generally divorced. Other information is generally organized by protecting authority. For instance, financial information would be separate from employment information. I am not a PII expert, so you'll have to do your own research, but this should point you in the right direction.

Side note: You don't need a specific _age field. You can calculate age by subtracting the _dob from the current date.

Comment: Instead of blind down votes, please comment as to how I can improve this answer. Thank you!